# Multiple App Signings With SMS Retriever API

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-hangouts, sms-retriever-api

I am working on the SMS Retriever API.I has successfully initiated the process with out current app signature but we need to upgrade the signature soon.
When we will do so, two app signatures will run on the users devices (the old signature for app updates and new signature for new installs).

I don't sure how to implement SMS Retriever API with 2 different 11-character hash strings base on the two signatures.

Can I generate one hash from two different signatures?
Or, what is the best way to handle those 2 hash strings for the same app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the SMS triggered? And, old version is already installed so nothing to.do there the has is already on the app code. New version will have another hash.

Comment: hi, sorry for the delay, we need somehow to support both two new hashes. The SMS triggered by server when the user is asking to fill OTP code. We are not sure if we need to deliver two codes and if the client should tell the server what hash to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved it by sending 2 hashes in same SMS.
Hope this will help to others.
Thanks.

Comment: Hey can you share more info on this? I'm having a similar issue. Did you put both of them at the end of message and Android picked the correct one up?